# Notepad++ count number of times a pattern appears in string and then do replace

Tags: regex, notepad++

I working on organizing some text that has a name and then several IPs listed behind it. Such as:

```
/bserver1-nfs01 10.61.53.206 10.61.53.207 10.61.53.208 10.61.53.209
```

into:

```
/bserver1-nfs01 10.61.53.206
/bserver1-nfs01 10.61.53.207 
/bserver1-nfs01 10.61.53.208 
/bserver1-nfs01 10.61.53.209
```

I am using the following find/replace command

find: `(/.*?\s)(\b\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\b)\s(\b\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\b)\s(\b\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\b)\s(\b\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\b)`

replace: `\1\2\n\1\3\n\1\4\n\1\5`

Works great, unless i have a line with fewer than 5 ip addresses then they are skipped.  Is there a simple way to make this an iterative call?  Like, count how many times this pattern occurs then replace that number?  Thanks, I've never used regex before today so all the help you can give me would be appreciated.

Gabe

Comment: I wanted to do something like this once and at the time (and probably still), Notepad++ couldn't do it, but TextPad can. (I still use Notepad++ for literally everything else that I can, but I needed Textpad for this). `\i` is the code for it.

Comment: thank you, i'll look at text pad.  however, the answer below does to trick too.

Comment: Is it always IP addresses that follow the server?

Comment: If your question has been answered then it would be useful to accept the answer. If the question has not been answered then please explain what additional information you need. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer

Answer (score 0):

I would approach this slightly differently. I would use a regular expression to change lines like this:

```
/bserver1-nfs01 10.61.53.206 10.61.53.207 10.61.53.208 10.61.53.209
```

into:

```
/bserver1-nfs01 10.61.53.206
/bserver1-nfs01 10.61.53.207 10.61.53.208 10.61.53.209
```

Then I would click the **Replace all** multiple times, until it reports that no changes have been made.

Thus I would alter your find expression to be:

```
^(/[^\s]+\s)(\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3})\s(\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3})
```

and for the replacement use:

```
\1\2\n\1\3
```

Comment: Okay, Thank you very much, I was over thinking it i guess.  your solution works quite well. Bravo

Comment: Thanks for the find expression w/NPP syntax. Supplied what I needed to match a single IP.